Is there a way to add vertical lines to histograms in R, where the line positions come from a separate data frame?
I have a data frame, from which I created a "stats" data frame (mean, min, max, median, Q1, etc), then I made facet_wrap histograms. Now I want to add vertical lines in each histogram based on the data columns from the "stats" data frame.  Adding a single line at x=0 works fine, but when adding min, mean or Q1, many lines are displayed instead of a single line representing the stat value.  Can anyone tell me where is the problem in my code:
# Generate data 
set.seed(123)

# Create a data frame with 10 columns and 100 rows
data <- data.frame(matrix(runif(1000, -3, 1), ncol = 10))

# Create a bimodal distribution in each column
for (i in 1:10) {
  data[,i] <- ifelse(runif(100) < 0.5, rnorm(100, -1, 0.5), rnorm(100, 0, 0.5))
}

# Print the first few rows of the data frame
head(data)


# Data Stats
data_stats <- data.frame(
  Mean = apply(data, 2, mean, na.rm = TRUE),
  SD = apply(data, 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE),
  Max = apply(data, 2, max, na.rm = TRUE),
  Median = apply(data, 2, median, na.rm=TRUE),
  Q1 = apply(data, 2, quantile, probs = 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),
  Min = apply(data, 2, min, na.rm =TRUE)
)


# --- Long data frame
data_long <- gather(data)

#---- Plot try 1
ggplot(data_long, aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 20) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "red") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = data_stats$Mean, linetype = "solid", color = "green") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = data_stats$Q1, linetype = "solid", color = "blue") +  
  geom_vline(xintercept = data_stats$Min, linetype = "solid", color = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = 'free')

#---- Plot try 2
ggplot(data_long, aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 20) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "red") +
  geom_vline(data = data_stats, aes(xintercept = Mean), linetype = "solid", color = "green") +
  geom_vline(data = data_stats, aes(xintercept = Q1), linetype = "solid", color = "blue") +  
  geom_vline(data = data_stats, aes(xintercept = Min), linetype = "solid", color = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = 'free')


Your data_stats dataframe has 10 rows and no "key" column, so you just get all ten values from each column in every facet. To fix it, add the rownames as a column and pivot to long format. You will save a few lines of plotting code by mapping color to the name column of the pivoted data frame, thus only needing a single geom_vline
library(tidyverse)

data_stats %>%
  mutate(zero = 0) %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "key") %>%
  pivot_longer(-key) %>%
  filter(name %in% c("Mean", "Q1", "Min", "zero")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 20, data = tidyr::gather(data)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = value, color = name)) +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c("green", "blue", "black", "red")) +
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = 'free') 



If you make sure key is a column in your stats dataframe then your second plot will follow the same facet wrapping:
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

# Create a data frame with 10 columns and 100 rows
data <- data.frame(matrix(runif(1000, -3, 1), ncol = 10))

# Create a bimodal distribution in each column
for (i in 1:10) {
  data[,i] <- ifelse(runif(100) < 0.5, rnorm(100, -1, 0.5), rnorm(100, 0, 0.5))
}

# Print the first few rows of the data frame
head(data)
#>           X1         X2          X3         X4          X5          X6
#> 1 -0.5775479 -0.5070571 -0.83428280 -0.5430591 -1.01089727 -1.64468209
#> 2  0.0535952 -0.3956569 -1.09492332 -0.3326514 -0.09009374 -1.32728432
#> 3 -0.4446443 -0.5723989 -0.76475363  0.3574242 -1.51794644 -0.01632923
#> 4 -0.7254122 -0.4235319  0.08655244 -0.8228239  0.32173432 -0.37162609
#> 5  0.2403128  0.5423085 -0.42104477  0.1138075 -0.54292063 -0.20627293
#> 6 -1.7294854 -0.3122837  0.05872979 -0.6758263 -0.77295833 -1.30201909
#>           X7         X8         X9         X10
#> 1 -1.0999336 -0.8960926 -0.9018373 -0.84150772
#> 2  0.8169948 -1.0926661 -0.5376290 -1.55086771
#> 3  0.2397259 -0.9842797  0.6290211 -1.71547923
#> 4  0.8573815 -0.2058489  0.7464859 -0.05399468
#> 5 -1.0059612 -1.3880919 -0.5312285 -0.06521094
#> 6 -0.8006640 -0.4301612 -1.6976029 -0.14680669


# Data Stats
data_stats <- data.frame(
  Mean = apply(data, 2, mean, na.rm = TRUE),
  SD = apply(data, 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE),
  Max = apply(data, 2, max, na.rm = TRUE),
  Median = apply(data, 2, median, na.rm=TRUE),
  Q1 = apply(data, 2, quantile, probs = 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),
  Min = apply(data, 2, min, na.rm =TRUE)
) |> 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("key")

# --- Long data frame
data_long <- tidyr::gather(data)


ggplot(data_long, aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 20) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "red") +
  geom_vline(data = data_stats, aes(xintercept = Mean), linetype = "solid", color = "green") +
  geom_vline(data = data_stats, aes(xintercept = Q1), linetype = "solid", color = "blue") +  
  geom_vline(data = data_stats, aes(xintercept = Min), linetype = "solid", color = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = 'free')


